# ets() function in R never stops

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to use the ets() function in R in my time series and when I run it, it never stops.

I know there should be something wrong as I also tried the code from a professor of a sample exercise who is supposed to work fine and got the same problem. R crashes and I have to close it and open again.

This is how my time series looks like:

```
data_ts
Time Series:
Start = c(3, 5) 
End = c(18, 2) 
Frequency = 7 
  [1] 152 100  54 199 166 143 162 116 136  68 176 181 120 141 205 118  62 152 135 180 172 180  82  96 193 209 146 189
 [29] 170  94  67 182 201 186 223 187  96  70 156 220 214 160 180 114  76 194 176 141 194 153 102 128 193 185 173 169
 [57] 171  95  80 137 147 163 183 165  78  88 169 172 169 190 123  76  50 147 126 159 172 162  92  79  99 125 171 182
 [85] 185  98  50 151 188 148 165 167  96  86 244 173 127 124 151 134  96 138 244
```

And this is the line of code I'm using:

```
data_ts.ets1 <- ets(data_ts, model = "ANA")
```

I also tried the default model = "ZZZ" and got the same problem. Before doing this, I used other functions with this time series (such as auto.arima()) and it worked fine.

I'm a student, so I'm not sure how to proceed or where to start to fix this problem. Any idea is welcome

--
Edit1: Just realised the first time I want to try to run the ets() function, the console says "No model able to be fitted". The second time I try it, it happens what I said before (run and never stops)

This is weird, because again, I'm having the same problem with my professor's code, who has for certain a model to be fitted.

--
Edit2: Tried to run it using forecast::ets instead of ets and have the same problem. Also tried to check if I have outdated packages, but no

--
Edit3:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forecast_8.15   devtools_2.4.2  usethis_2.1.3   ggplot2_3.3.5   dplyr_1.0.7     tseries_0.10-48

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lattice_0.20-41   prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.5.0          zoo_1.8-8         rprojroot_2.0.2  
 [7] assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     lmtest_0.9-38     utf8_1.1.4        R6_2.5.1          evaluate_0.14    
[13] pillar_1.6.4      rlang_0.4.12      curl_4.3          fracdiff_1.5-1    callr_3.7.0       TTR_0.24.2       
[19] rmarkdown_2.6     desc_1.4.0        labeling_0.4.2    stringr_1.4.0     munsell_0.5.0     compiler_4.0.3   
[25] xfun_0.18         pkgconfig_2.0.3   pkgbuild_1.2.0    urca_1.3-0        htmltools_0.5.0   nnet_7.3-14      
[31] tidyselect_1.1.0  tibble_3.0.3      quadprog_1.5-8    fansi_0.4.2       crayon_1.4.2      withr_2.4.2      
[37] grid_4.0.3        nlme_3.1-149      jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.1        
[43] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      quantmod_0.4.18   cli_3.1.0         stringi_1.5.3     cachem_1.0.6     
[49] farver_2.0.3      remotes_2.4.1     fs_1.5.0          testthat_3.1.0    timeDate_3043.102 ellipsis_0.3.2   
[55] xts_0.12.1        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8       tools_4.0.3       glue_1.4.2        purrr_0.3.4      
[61] pkgload_1.2.3     processx_3.5.2    parallel_4.0.3    fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_1.4-1 
[67] sessioninfo_1.2.1 memoise_2.0.0     knitr_1.30
```

--
**Final Edit**:
It worked after I updated **all** the packages in RStudio. Not only the packages attached at the beginning of my code (like forecast package) but all of the outdated packages in my RStudio.
So, not sure why, but problem solved.

Comment: Did you use `forecast::ets`? It works well for me.

Comment: Please provide your dataset using `dput(data_ts)` to make it easier to run your example code.

Comment: structure(c(152, 100, 54, 199, 166, 143, 162, 116, 136, 68, 176, 
181, 120, 141, 205, 118, 62, 152, 135, 180, 172, 180, 82, 96, 
193, 209, 146, 189, 170, 94, 67, 182, 201, 186, 223, 187, 96, 
70, 156, 220, 214, 160, 180, 114, 76, 194, 176, 141, 194, 153, 
102, 128, 193, 185, 173, 169, 171, 95, 80, 137, 147, 163, 183, 
165, 78, 88, 169, 172, 169, 190, 123, 76, 50, 147, 126, 159, 
172, 162, 92, 79, 99, 125, 171, 182, 185, 98, 50, 151, 188, 148, 
165, 167, 96, 86, 244, 173, 127, 124, 151, 134, 96, 138, 244), .Tsp = c(3.57142857142857, 
18.1428571428571, 7), class = "ts")

Comment: Which version of forecast do you have? packageVersion('forecast') version 8.14 seems to work on my machine.

Comment: @OttoKässi 8.15 is my package. Should I try to install an older version?

Tried doing: 
require(devtools)
install_version("forecast", version = "8.14", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

But got a message: "installation of package had non-zero exit status"

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error with forecast version 8.15. Could you attach the output of sessionInfo() into your question? Perhaps that could give some hints.

Comment: @OttoKässi added in Edit3 at the original question

Comment: I am still unable to spot anything that would be obviously wrong. Perhaps you could find some info by loading `library(evaluate)` and running `evaluate({ ets(data_ts, model='ANA') } )`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time anyway. Tried to run that evaluate() function, but it also runs indefinitely